# GROUP BY without limit on a large DB

Tags: database, sqlite, group-by, sql-order-by

I have 2 tables that are supposed to log traffic stats. First one contains the visitor info and the second one contains the pages visited.

Then I have this query which is suppose to get me a list of browsers used sorted by # of visits.

```
SELECT tu.browser, COUNT(tp.id) AS count FROM t_users tu 
   LEFT JOIN t_pages tp ON tu.id = tp.id GROUP BY tu.browser
```

I was wondering if this query is still efficient if there are millions of records in these tables.

Note that I have indexes on all the columns I use in the query.

Comment: Have you tried running `EXPLAIN` on the query?  If you have indices setup properly, then my guess is that the query would be reasonably fast.

Comment: EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN shows one "scan using index" and 2 "search using index". Is that good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out whether this query runs fast with your data on your hardware, you have to measure it yourself.

Anyway, this query already is pretty efficient.
The join can be done with the index on `t_pages.id`, and the GROUP BY is very efficient by scanning the entries of the index on `t_users.browser` in order.
However, if `t_users.id` is not the `rowid`, i.e., if it is not declared as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, then looking it up from the index entry requires going to the actual table; you could remove this step by adding a [covering index](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#covidx) that contains both the `browser` and `id` fields.